# DC/OS: modifying Cluster name post installation

Tags: mesosphere, dcos

I missed to update the cluster name (cluster_name) in my boot node's genconf/config.yaml before deploying the DC/OS cluster.  I was wondering if there's a configuration/properties file in the nodes (or using dcos-cli or in etcd) that I need to change to update the cluster name string (that appears on the DC/OS UI).  'appreciate any help.

```
version: DC/OS 1.8 
nodes running on CoreOS 
size: 3 masters and 11 agents
```

Answer (score 0):

The cluster name that appears on the DC/OS interface is extracted from the Mesos cluster name. According to this configuration generation file it's possible to change the name of [the environment variable](https://github.com/dcos/dcos/blob/1.8/gen/dcos-config.yaml#L238). Obviously you're going to have to restart the Mesos master one by one.

**Important note**: I have not had the possibility to test it, if you are in a production environment I highly recommend you not to do.